# Angularjs : Not able to print from controller

Tags: angularjs

I am learning angularjs and just run the basic example of it.

However very first didnt work.

here is the detail.

[image]

Now here is index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="Hello.js"></script>
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="Hello">
            <p>The ID is {{greeting.id}}</p>
            <p>The content is {{greeting.content}}</p>
        </div>
    </body>    
</body>    
</html>
```

here is the controller :

```
function Hello($scope, $http) {   
    $scope.greeting = [{content : 'sdfsfd',id:'2'}];
}
```

Please help me out :)

Comment: your example looks very old.

Comment: You really shouldn't try using angular 1.0.8 for anything;  it uses a very old syntax, and isn't compatible with many currently available libraries.

Answer (score 1):

You should define your application using ng-app first.
I think this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <title>Insert title here</title>

</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">

    <div ng-controller="Hello">
        <p>The ID is {{sample[0].id}}</p>
        <p>The content is {{sample[0].content}}</p>

    </div>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        app.controller('Hello', function ($scope) {
            debugger
            $scope.sample = [
                     { content: 'sdfsfd', id: 2 }
            ];
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```